# JAVA reading integers from a file to two different arrays

Tags: java

My in-file looks like that.

```
3 5 7 9
2 4 6 5
```

I want the values from the first line, put into **arrayA**, and values from the second line into **arrayB**. That's what I have for now.

```
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                arrA[i] = sc.nextInt();
                arrB[i] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do the lines always contain 4 integers?

Comment: You cannot handle both lines at the same time. You need to read one line and fill arrA, then the second line to fill arrB.

Comment: It should be a parameter, they can contain up to 12 integers.

Answer (score 1):

may be like this

```
String s = sc.readLine();
Integer[] arrA = Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReadFileToArray {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("./abc.txt");
    List<List<char[]>> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<>();

    if (Files.exists(path)) {
        List<String> readAllLines = Files.readAllLines(path);
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(readAllLines)) {
            readAllLines.forEach(line -> {
                if (Objects.nonNull(line)) {
                    listOfArrays.add(Collections.singletonList(line.toCharArray()));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(listOfArrays)) {
        listOfArrays.forEach(listOfArray -> listOfArray.forEach(System.out::println));
    }
} }
```

File : abc.txt

3 5 7 9

2 4 6 5

**Output:**

3 5 7 9

2 4 6 5